# What's an alternative for the word "profile" in the context of computer software/data (and not relating to people or users)?

Tags: technical, synonyms

I'm a software/database developer and struggling to find the correct term for what we are currently referring to in our software as "**profile**". Of all the definitions I found for the word *profile*, these two are the closest but still inaccurate for our use:

- a user's summary of their personal details or current situation.
- a record of a person's psychological or behavioral characteristics, preferences, etc.

These seem to relate more directly to people. I'm happy to continue using the term in relation to people, such as Person profile or User profile. However, we are using the term for many more things in our software. Whenever we are editing basic information on an entity in our database we refer to it as "updating the [fill-in-the-blank] profile" (ie. school profile, team profile, game profile, etc.). What's a more appropriate alternative for these types of record keeping chunks of basic data?

**Edit**: 
The word *record* would not be a good fit since we are involved in school sports. (ie. team record would be confusing). The term would preferably be used internally (in code) and also on user-interface screens for editing and viewing.

**Update**: It was a tough choice between *details* and *info*, but we decided to go with *details*. It seems to have a bit more appeal since it is not a short-form of a word. I also feel it gives a little more attraction for users to click on and pairs nicely with the word *view* (as in "view details"). The word *details* also pulled up a whole new set of synonyms that were good candidates. There are two things in computer programming that are generally considered to be the hardest. One of those things is "naming things".

Comment: Programmatically that would depend on what the profile is. If it's a schema, you would update the table, if it's a table, you would update a record, if it's a record, you would update the field.

Comment: It's a set of fields that you would find on a row in a database table (but not necessarily all fields on that row). Some times I find myself thinking of using "basic details". But I don't like the two words. "Details" by itself seems too generic (although I'm looking for something generic I suppose).

Comment: So it's a record?

Comment: Oh that might have been a good fit @Ajaypayne. But we are involved in school sports, so the word "record" is reserved. I'll update my question to note that.

Comment: A little more database centric then, how about tuple?

Comment: Lol, hard no. You went too far database centric I'd say. The word "profile" is actually being used in the user-interface screens. So "tuple" would be confusing to most.

Comment: Okay, how does attributes work for you? I actually think that would fit quite well based on what you've said so far?

Comment: Well profile seems to suggest the attributes as a whole. Your attributes make up your profile.

Comment: I'm leaning towards just the word "details". It's generic, but at least it's not incorrect like profile (which relates to people/users).

Comment: Methods in my code could call functions "updateDetails" and on the screen I can simply say "School Details" or "Team Details". To mix it up a bit, I can continue to use "Profile" for users and people.

Comment: Ah, so this is to display as well, not just for internal use?

Comment: Yeah, it's for both.

Comment: @Ajaypayne, you want to create an answer and I'll accept it. You helped me come to the conclusion of "details" so feel free to post that. Doesn't seem like anyone else has come up with something better.

Comment: One last question, who is the target demographic? You said about schools, so is this for faculty, students, or parents?

Comment: All 3 of those are targeted. Mostly faculty though.

Comment: "Info" is pretty good too I just realized. Update your answer to include that one in there. Great answer, should be helpful for others.

Comment: Info is so simple that it hadn't even entered my mind once! Lol

Comment: ^ yes, same here!

Comment: @Ajaypayne see my update in my question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the data and knowing the spec, all I can offer are generic words. 'Details' as you have suggested will cover it and be clear in the meaning for all of your users. As well as my suggestions in the comments on you question, I would also say 'chronicle', 'particulars', and 'specifics' could work well.

I personally would go with 'profile' or 'details' like you have said, if it wasn't for the fact that 'record' was a reserved word, that would have been the one for me :)

Answer (score 3):

I find that in these situations, simpler is often better.  You could try just using "Information" or "Account."  Neither is jargon-y and both convey the general meaning.  Another more technical-sounding alternative might be "Data."

Comment: Ah, nice. Also "info" for short as well.

Answer (score 0):

Statistics/stats  -- MW definition:  a collection of quantitative data.
or
At my company we use the word Demographics for our assorted member data, but the dictionary only had demographic which has a slightly different meaning.
For us, member demographics include where they are, contact information, licensure, relationships etc.